# mysql query on database using composite design pattern

Tags: mysql

I'm not an SQL expert and therefore am having trouble wrapping my head around designing a mysql query to query database tables designed using the "composite design pattern."

The tables are:

composites:
id, name, type [type is either "Condition" or "ConditionGroup"]

composites_properties:
id, composite_id, property_id

groupings:
id, parent_id, child_id

properties: id, key, value

What I want to do is generate a query that will return the unique properties of the group's ("ConditionGroup") member conditions ("Condition") such that I end up with a Group Name and a list of Property Keys (inherited from the member conditions).

The best I've come up with is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT properties.`key`, composites.name  
FROM composites, composites_properties, properties  
WHERE composites.id=composites_properties.composite_id
AND properties.id=composites_properties.property_id  
AND composites.id IN (
    SELECT child_id FROM groupings WHERE parent_id IN
        (SELECT id FROM composites WHERE type='ConditionGroup')
    )
```

This yields each member condition along with its list of properties where the properties are repeated if more than one member condition has that property.

In the end I'd like:

Group Name

- property_1
- property_2
- property_3

But I'm getting the following type list (with no indication to which group the conditions belong)

Condition Name 1  property_1

Condition Name 1  property_2

Condition Name 1  property_3

Condition Name 2  property_1

Condition Name 2  property_2

Condition Name 3  property_1

Condition Name 3  property_2

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm a little unclear on exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but I'll give it a shot.  If you can clarify how this query does not do what you want, I can probably help further.

```
SELECT      c.name, p.key
FROM        composites c
INNER JOIN  groupings g ON c.id = g.parent_id
INNER JOIN  composites_properties cp ON cp.composite_id = g.child_id
INNER JOIN  properties p ON p.id = cp.property_id
WHERE       c.type = 'ConditionGroup'
```

This doesn't seem like the best query in the world to me because it ignores what the children in each grouping actually are, so I'm not sure this is what you want.

Comment: Oh wow.  I was not thinking like this at all. I was making it much harder by thinking I had to do many loops within loops.  Adding DISTINCT to p.key gets me very close, if not there.  Thanks!

Comment: @stuck_in_a_loop Well, actually, DISTINCT on the whole SELECT clause plus an ORDER BY c.name, p.key at the end will probably be closer in practice, I think.  Make sure this actually gives you the results you want, though.  For instance, would you want to know the names of the composites that were children of the composites of type 'ConditionGroup'?  Just a thought.

Comment: I'm able to get (most) everything I want from a "Condition" perspective (which groups it belongs to and its properties), but I was having a hard time figuring out how to determine a group's properties (inherited) from the children.  I think what you've written is pretty close to it.  I just need to make sure that where a condition belongs to more than one group that the inherited properties are still reflected.  I'll try adding DISTINCT to the whole clause and ORDER BY as well.  Thanks again.

Comment: @stuck_in_a_loop I think the inherited properties will be reflected even when a condition belongs to multiple groups.  However, I don't see that properties directly on a composite are actually included, which isn't a problem if you know that ConditionGroups will never have properties directly.  If that is not the case, however, you will have issues.  Also, this query only looks one level deep; if any children of ConditionGroups also have children with properties, they will not be reflected in this query.